# Magento2 Custom JQuery file included correctly but code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, magento2

I have added a custom js file named `myweb.js` in the path
`/app/code/Ced/CsProduct/view/frontend/web/js/`

The code is like this:

```
require([
    "jquery"
    ], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Hello");
    $("[data-index='painting_hieght']").hide();
    $("[name='product[size]']").change(function(){
     var status = this.value;
     alert(status);
   if(status=="103"){
      $("[data-index='painting_hieght'],[data-index='painting_width']").show();// hide multiple sections
        }else {
            $("[data-index='painting_hieght'],[data-index='painting_width']").hide();
        }
  });
    });
   });
```

and modified the file `csproduct_vproducts_simple.xml`
in path
`app/code/Ced/CsProduct/view/frontend/layout/`

the contents of the file look like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

        <head>
        <link src="Ced_CsProduct::js/myweb.js"/>
        </head>
    <update handle="csproduct_vproducts_superconfig_config"/>
</page>
```

I am getting the alert `hello` correctly, which means that the file is included correctly.
but the code after that doesn't seems to work, though I have tested the code working in firebug console.

What I am missing here?

**Update:**

on further observation I find that I get the alert "Hello" only First time after clearing all cache.
but subsequent reload doesn't show any alert.
Besides the page source shows the `myweb.js`
but in firebug debugger source the file is not there.

Obviously I am making some silly error, which is skipping my attention.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem correct approach. (my view)

You need `requirejs-config.js` in this path `/app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/web/js/` with below content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom_js: 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/js_file_name'
        }
    }
};
```

In a template you can call it:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'custom_js'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
        //alert('Here');
    });
```

You can check a nice explaination by `St3phan` in below threads as well :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/magento2-add-js-from-admin-cms-page-design-layout-update-xml

Hope that helps!